# CSS: Scrollbar starts few pixels below the window

Tags: html, css, position, scrollbar, move

I'd like to have my header fixed: header is always at the top of page and my whole content (everything including footer) could be scrolled. Header is 60 px high as you can see below and it's not the problem to make it fixed at the top.

The problem I want to solve (using only CSS) is **to have scrollbar starting below these 60 pixels from the top.** 
As you can see, the bottom of the scrollbar (2. arrow) is actually hidden/moved down. I guess by my problematic 60px.
So it goes like this:

[image: scrollbar]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        ...
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #d0d0d0;
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}

header { 
    background: #fff;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}


#content {
    margin-top: 60px;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;

    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

What am I missing in my CSS? 
Thanks guys.

// **Edit** as a reply to the forst answer here (to John Grey)

Commentary below your comment:

[image: scrollbar_2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle how to solve your problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/sTSFJ/2/

Here is the css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}

#content {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    top: 40px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #666;
}​
```

Comment: It's almost perfect. Now I need to place my header above the scrollbar - especially the shadow. It (these 4px of shadow) should be above the scrollbar. Using z-index: 5; in header{} and z-index: -1; in #content isn't helping.

Look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jBfwY/

Comment: This solution is problematic because requires to know the height of the header in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your #content height is equal body height, but you have a header so... Try use this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #d0d0d0;
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}

header { 
    background: #fff;
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}


#content {
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 95%; 
    width: 100%;

    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. I already tried this and it works only with specific window height.

Look at this: approx. 300px vs 900px height of the browser window
(check the second image in my first post)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using the calc property. That is instead of height 95%, since you don't know if 5% == 60px rather do the following:-

```
#content {
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: calc(100%-60px); 
    height: -webkit-calc(100%-60px); /*For webkit browsers eg safari*/
    height: -moz-cal(100%-60px); /*for firefox*/
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```