# How to get the header out of the scroll area?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a header and a long scrollable content. I'd like the header to not be scrollable. I tried setting `overflow: hidden` to the header but without success.

How can I get the header out of the scroll area?

Snippet:

```
<body>
  <div style="overflow: hidden">Header</div>
  <div style="overflow: scroll">Content - very long Content...
```

See [a Plunker with this code](http://plnkr.co/edit/CNIcugToU7ij9132KId2?p=preview).

I also tried setting styles in the body - without success.

I know there's [a way to make the header fixed using position fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3593599/435605), but I don't want to use it because it requires to know the height of the header in advance (for the margin). This requires size duplication and if the header is more complicated, it requires computation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3593594/435605

Answer (score 4):

Found the flex magic.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O7E6gl?p=preview)'s an example of how to do a fixed header and a scrollable content. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Holy Grail</title>
    <!-- Reset browser defaults -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  </head>
  <body style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
    <div>HEADER<br/>------------
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
        CONTENT - START<br/>
        <script>
        for (var i=0 ; i<1000 ; ++i) {
          document.write(" Very long content!");
        }
        </script>
        <br/>CONTENT - END
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For a full [Holy Grail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_(web_design)) implementation (header, footer, nav, side, and content), using flex display, go to [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/swHKE2?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Remove your inline styles first.
Then add this css.

```
html , body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;

}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sthsuuec/11/

Comment: I edited the link, stackoverflow is currently really laggy for me.

Comment: In jsfiddle (new link) the code above works fine! Nice anwser - nice question. Thumbs up guys.

Comment: It seems that the bottom of the content is pushed below the window. You can see it more clearly if you make the header higher. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Yes I have an idea, you do it the way everyone does their fixed headers. You put it as a position:fixed.

What you ask for is not possible without using positioning.
Or give fixed height to your content. That could work too https://jsfiddle.net/sthsuuec/12/

Comment: A question related to the hidden bottom content: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13193197/435605